# Querying for historical asset state in HyperLedger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Given two classes:

```
export class Person {
    public name: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public address: Address;

}


export class Address {
    public city: string;
    public street: string;
}
```

How would one query to see the changes to a `Person` `address` field? For example if you would like to check where some one lived in the year 2000

Answer (score 0):

If you use MongoDB to hold your world state, you can perform so called Mango queries to retrieve all records that satisfy your request. If you write your application in Node.js, you could use the [sqltomango](https://github.com/glynnbird/sqltomango) package to convert SQL queries to Mango.

All these options however only apply on the *current* state data, not historical. To see how an object has been modified, or to see if any object at any point in time matched your search criteria, you can iterate through the historical blocks and check the transactions contained in them.

Comment: Thank you for your input if you could show an example in NodeJS SDK or Java SDK how to iterate through historical blocks. Also is it possible to recreate the world state for a given historical block and query that DB? If so how?